# Mudar framework de uma versão para uma mais recente

Tags: c#, framework, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um projeto *.NET*(c#) criado no *Framework 2.0*. Essa solution contém 11 projetos. Preciso agora atualizar tudo para o *Framework 4.7*(o mais recente). Qual seria o meu procedimento para isso? Uso *VS 2017 Community*.

Comment: Vá nas propriedades de cada projeto, altere o target framework e resolva os conflitos de códigos e dependências. Mas por que você precisa fazer essa migração?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clique com o botão direito no solution explorer do seu projeto
2. Selecione Propriedades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Selecione a guia Aplicativo
4. Alterar o `framework` de destino para o `framework` desejado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Nota**
>
> Se o seu código contiver referências a uma versão diferente do .NET
> Framework que você tenha direcionado, mensagens de erro poderão
> aparecer quando você compilar ou executar o código. Para resolver
> esses erros, você deve modificar as referências. Consulte [Solução de
> problemas de erros de segmentação do .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/troubleshooting-dotnet-framework-targeting-errors?view=vs-2017).
>
> [Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-target-a-version-of-the-dotnet-framework?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Isso eu fiz e já está ok, vou até encerrar a pergunta. É que quebrou muita coisa, principalmente os serviços WCF, na linha ServiceHostFactory. Mas é outra pergunta.